# Take copies of virtual machines without shutting them down

Tags: backup

What tool do you recommend for taking backup copies of my VMs when they run VMware Workstation on Windows 7?

I have a couple of VMs which are now sort of "always-on" and I don't really want to have them shut down for a backup.

Answer (score 3):

VMware Workstation lets you take snapshot of running VMs provided that the VM doesn't use independent disks:

[image]

From the [official manual](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/desktop/ws10-using.pdf):

> Take a Snapshot of a Virtual Machine
>
> When you take a snapshot, you preserve the state of a virtual machine
>   at a specific moment in time and the virtual machine continues to run.
>   Taking a snapshot enables you to return to the same state repeatedly.
>   You can take a snapshot while a virtual machine is powered on, powered
>   off, or suspended.
>
> Avoid taking snapshots when applications in the virtual machine are
>   communicating with other computers, especially in production
>   environments. For example, if you take a snapshot while the virtual
>   machine is downloading a file from a server on the network, the
>   virtual machine continues downloading the file after you take the
>   snapshot. If you revert to the snapshot, communications between the
>   virtual machine and the server are confused and the file transfer
>   fails.
>
> Prerequisites
>
> - Verify that the virtual is not configured to use a physical disk. You cannot take a snapshot of a virtual machine that uses a physical
>     disk.
> - To have the virtual machine revert to suspend, power on, or power off when you start it, be sure it is in that state before you take the
>     snapshot. When you revert to a snapshot, you return the memory,
>     settings, and virtual disks of the virtual machine to the state they
>     were in when you took the snapshot.
> - Complete any suspend operations.
> - Verify that the virtual machine is not communicating with another computer.
> - For better performance, defragment the guest operating system drives.
> - If the virtual machine has multiple disks in different disk modes, power off the virtual machine. For example, if a configuration
>     requires you to use an independent disk, you must power off the
>     virtual machine before you take a snapshot.
> - If the virtual machine was created with Workstation 4, delete any existing snapshots or upgrade the virtual machine to Workstation 5.x
>     or later.
>
> Procedure
>
> 1. Select the virtual machine and select VM > Snapshot > Take Snapshot.
> 2. Type a unique name for the snapshot.
> 3. (Optional) Type a description for the snapshot. The description is useful for recording notes about the virtual machine state captured in
>      the snapshot.
> 4. Click OK to take the snapshot.

Comment: thanks Franck! However, I forgot to mention I want the copies to be completely off my laptop. Like a copy to my desktop PC in case the laptop is stolen. Also, would be cool to have another copy go to a USB drive. I am getting paranoid about losing my stuff ;-)

Comment: Snapshots are not copies. Clones cannot be made from suspended or running VMs.

Answer (score 0):

A buddy of mine in Canada recommended [Backup Chain](http://backupchain.com/) that they use mainly for Hyper-V and suggested I give it a shot for VMware Workstation. I'm now playing with the trial to see how it works and will post a screenshot with more info later. 
What I like so far is the compression option that builds increments from day to day. What I haven't checked yet is how it handles VMware snapshots...